# Distributed tensorflow with authentication

Tags: tensorflow, distributed, grpc

I am running a distributed tensorflow application on multiple machines on my network. When I `ssh` to these machines I need to enter my login and password. When I run the application parameter server says that it started server, worker says that it is waiting for the ps (`Error: CreateSession still waiting for response from worker tensorflow: /job/replica:0/task:0`). I believe firewalls on the machines don't allow them to connect. I found the instructions to turn off the firewall

```
machineA$ sudo ufw allow from machineB
```

But is there a way to pass the authentication information (login, password) with the firewalls on?